# get a random venue with foursquare API

Tags: php, random, foursquare

i try to find a  way to find random venue to post random check-in with a php script.
I have tried with a random Lat/Long but most of my try have finished into ocean, even if i use the radius parameters to extend the area os research.

Any ideas?

Thks.

Comment: Need to actually show some code before anyone can help.

Comment: Do you intend just to know some area which you can set as a test area for your check-ins? Then as an idea - take some Long/Lat from google maps search and set it as an area, with some radius to search in this area.
The reason about oceans... Well, they are 3/4 of Earth, as far as I remember. So random string and some bad luck would state that at least 3 of 4 tries would end there.

Comment: here an example of two random Lat/lng with no results `https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fintent%3Dbrowse%26query%3Dmcd%26ll%3D86.168,77.565%26radius%3D99999`.
the idea is to avoid the ocean problem :s

Comment: the best way i find for the moment is to get a database of all (big)cities in the world.